# Question about DS-160 arrival and departure flight

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa

I want to go from Costa Rica to San Francisco, but there is a connection in Charlotte. So, should I put both of those flights on the form, or just the one I take from CR to Charlotte? Same accurs in the departure flight.

Comment: It is [rather risky](http://trinidad.usembassy.gov/should_i_buy_my_plane_ticket_before_getting_a_visa.html) to purchase tickets before you receive your visa, as most plane tickets are non-refundable (unless you've paid substantially more), and you run the risk of having tickets you can't use if your visa is denied. You don't need pre-purchased tickets to apply for a visa as long as you can show that you're able to buy them.

Answer (score 3):

The arrival flight is the flight number of the flight which first lands in the US having departed from another country. So this will be the flight which lands in Charlotte. (Example: AA1706)

The departure flight is the flight number of the flight which takes off from the US and lands in another country. (Example: AA1707)

Don't worry if you have to change your itinerary later. These are used in part to verify that your proposed itinerary makes sense with the rest of your application.